# How to avoid setState in useEffect hook causing second render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing a custom hook that takes an id as input and then should do the following tasks:

- get data for that id synchronously from a store
- subscribe to changes in this store and update data accordingly

I came up with the following implementation which has the downside that I am setting state directly from inside the effect hook, causing a second render.

```
function useData({id}) {
    // set initial data on first render
    const [data, setData] = useState(Store.getData(id));

    useEffect(() => {
        // when id changes, set data to whatever is in store at the moment
        // here we call setData directly from inside useEffect, causing a second render
        setData(Store.getData(id));
        // subscribe to changes to update data whenever it changes in the store
        return Store.onChange(id, setData);
    }, [id]);

    return data;
}
```

A second approach I tried was to add a dummy state that is only there to cause a re-render. In this approach I am directly returning the data received from Store.getData(). This ensures that I will get the freshest data with every render and the useEffect ensures that every onChange trigger will cause a new render.

```
function useData({id}) {
    // adding some dummy state that we only use to force a render
    const [, setDummy] = useState({});
    const refresh = useCallback(() => {
        setDummy({});
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        // subscribe to changes cause a refresh on every change
        return Store.onChange(id, refresh);
    }, [id, refresh]);

    return Store.getData[id];
}
```

The second approach works well but it feels weird to add this dummy state. Sure, I could put this into another useRefresh hook but I am not sure if this would really be a good practice.

Is there any better way of implementing this, without calling setData directly from inside useEffect and without relying on some unused dummy state?

Comment: @skyboyer I do need up to date date to be rendered. What indicates to you that I don't? And yes, I subscribe to changes on the data for a particular id. The idea is that `.onChange(id, handler)` executes `handler` whenever the data for that id changes. This is why I execute the effect on every id change. I didn't mention that, but `onChange` actually returns an unsubscribe function and I then return that unsubscribe function in the effect to ensure all handlers are cleaned up, so no memory leak.

Comment: sorry, was wrong on first and second you say is not an issue. deleted my comments as misleading.

Answer (score 0):

So by now you use `useState` inside your hook just to re-trigger rendering of host component once store is changed. How about taking change handler from the outside?

```
function useData(id, onChanged) {
  useEffect(() => {
    return store.onChange(id, onChanged);
  }, [id, onChanged]);

 return store.getData(id);
}
```